# Existence of canonical form for cubic and quartic form?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, transformation, quadratic-forms, canonical-transformation

I am a post graduate student who is currently studying some optimization for quadratic form. From the class lecture, I know that we can always turn any quadratic functions into theirs corresponding canonical form using some changes of variable.

For example: $f\left( {x,y} \right) = x \times y$ can be rewritten as $f\left( {X,Y} \right) = \frac{1}{4}{X^2} - \frac{1}{4}{Y^2}$ through the following change of variable $\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{X = x + y}\\
{Y = x - y}
\end{array}} \right.$.

Out of pure curiosity, my question is:

Does "**canonical cubic form**" and "**canonical quartic form**" for function of the form $f\left( {x,y,z} \right) = xyz$ and $g\left( {x,y,z,t} \right) = xyzt$ respectively even existed ?

If these canonical form existed then what would be a systematic way to find them ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !